# How to add custom properties to media field

Tags: strapi

Currently Media field has couple of text attributes out of the box: File name, Alternative text and Caption.

We would like to extend this by adding text property for geolocation and relation property for author.

Currently we are solving this problem by creating a new [component](https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/content-type-builder/configuring-fields-content-type#-components) but it would be very convinient to add those attributes to media object directly.

I'm sure there are some yaml's out there and also I found [frontend asset dialog](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/6b2e0dc72db42f8aceb98da87865d9300c298375/packages/core/upload/admin/src/components/EditAssetDialog/index.js) - what would be the correct way to extend the media object?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope. have not researched it on our own yet, too.

Comment: For now, I've experienced Strapi version upgrade of quite complex installation and I think the component approach was good idea.